# Broadcast Receiver for discover bluetooth devices not working

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, broadcast, receiver

Hello i have followed the example in https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth and my broadcast receiver maybe is not working. I am running android 8.1 in my Android Xiaomi mi A1 device.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
bluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

    IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);
    bluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();
}
private final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
            // Discovery has found a device. Get the BluetoothDevice
            // object and its info from the Intent.
            BluetoothDevice device = (BluetoothDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
            String deviceName = device.getName();
            String deviceHardwareAddress = device.getAddress(); // MAC address
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, deviceName, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, deviceHardwareAddress, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            mDeviceList.add(deviceHardwareAddress);
            ArrayAdapter arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(MainActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,mDeviceList);
            listV.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
        }
    }
};
```

Thank you!

**NOTE**

For android Api 21 Broadcast receiver works fine is there a change i have to make to make it work for Android 8.1?

Comment: Hi, i too have the same issue. Did you find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

In manifest I have put the permissions and other services like start stop bluetooth and find paired devices are working fine...

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**You Need to Add Permission in code above Version M**

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
            requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1000);
```